# How do I create a unique public id column which is not primary key

Tags: sql, web, primary-key

I read somewhere that **it is bad to use your db table's primary key as a public identifier** online. However, I would like my users to link to a specific object in the table.

**How do I create a unique identifier column** to my table that is non-related to the primary key (which is a auto-increment integer)?

My initial idea is to use a php script to generate random hexadecimal values of suitable length (there will be about 100 000-200 000 items i the table at most I think) and then inserting them. But then I don't know if it would be unique...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a GUID (Globally Unique IDentifier) to uniquely identify a record. The number of possible GUIDs is so high the chances of duplicating one is next to nothing. Similarly, the chances of someone guessing the GUID is so low that generally they are safe to display to the user (for example www.yoursite.com?id=21EC20203AEA1069A2DD08002B30309D).

If you're using php you can use the `com_create_guid` [method](http://php.net/manual/en/function.com-create-guid.php). *Note: This method is only supported in PHP5. For PHP4, look at [uniqueid](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.uniqid.php).

Comment: Yept, that's usually my way to deal with this need, except I use UUIDs in Java: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/UUID.html. I understand GUID is the way Microsoft call them.